# Dynamic Paint Brush Erase doesn't work in Render Output

Tags: cycles-render-engine, dynamic-paint

Got some problems when trying erase colors with a Dynamic paint brush.

I have plane which is affected by particles Dynamic paint brush (surface & color).
When I try erase some spaces on the plane it works in 3D view but not with render output. So how to make render output work?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried clearing the dynamic paint cache? Or using an image sequence? I recall image sequence working better under some conditions.

Comment: It's hard to say exactly what's causing the issue in your case without more information. Is possible you could upload your .blend?